# Factory Pattern - Example in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, oop, factory

I'm trying to get a better grip on the Factory Pattern as illustrated here:

http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

The examples are in Java, and I'm not a very strong Java programmer. I mostly don't understand the `Constructor product ... = cClass... String.class` line. I think I've got the "concept," but are these two code blocks analogous?

Furthermore, is there an example in Cocoa Foundation that uses this pattern? The only one I can think of is in UIKit registering cell classes against a `UITableView`.

**Java:**

```
class ProductFactory
{
    private HashMap m_RegisteredProducts = new HashMap();

    public void registerProduct (String productID, Class productClass)
    {
        m_RegisteredProducts.put(productID, productClass);
    }

    public Product createProduct(String productID)
    {
        Class productClass = (Class)m_RegisteredProducts.get(productID);
        Constructor productConstructor = cClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
        return (Product)productConstructor.newInstance(new Object[] { });
    }
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
@interface ProductFactory : NSObject

- (void)registerProduct:(Class)productClass withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (id)newProductForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

@end

@interface ProductFactory();

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *registeredProducts;

@end

@implementation ProductFactory

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _registeredProducts = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)registerProduct:(Class)productClass withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    self.registeredProducts[identifier] = NSStringFromClass(productClass);
}

- (id)newProductForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    NSString *classString = self.registeredProducts[identifier];
    Class productClass = NSClassFromString(classString);

    return [[productClass alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is generally analogous. I haven't done java for a little while so I can't explicitly explain the `Constructor` line but it's kind of like the definition of a designated initialiser and how to find it.

You could do a little work with `@protocol`s to allow a range of init methods to be available for the instantiation and interrogate the class to see which protocol it conforms to (using `conformsToProtocol:`).

Comment: Neat idea about ```conformsToProtocol:```!